# How to add text inside mat-progress-spinner with using angular material only

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular9

I am using angular material and want to use mat-progress-spinner to achieve something like it as shown in the image below :

[image]

Let me share the code snippet for the same which i have done till now.

```
<mat-progress-spinner color="accent" style="position: absolute;" [mode]="mode" [value]=100 [strokeWidth]=6 [diameter]=80></mat-progress-spinner>
<mat-progress-spinner color="warn"  [mode]="mode" [value]=60 [strokeWidth]=6 [diameter]=80></mat-progress-spinner>
<div style="position:relative; top: -48px; left: 30px;">30%</div>
```

With this i am able to get same as desired but i do not want to use the last line of code i.e. I do not want to use additional div for it.

Is there any possible way with which i can extend mat-progress-spinner and achieve it with material only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with material only. However if you want to have just one component to call to do this without having to add a div each time what you can do is create a custom component which will contain the spinners and the div and when you'll use it you will just have one line to write.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
I can understand that part that i can create a reusable component for it. But actually i do not want to use the additional div because it has the position adjustments like relative or absolute which might break page responsiveness some where.

so it is really good if i can do it with material only

Comment: what you can do if you really want this is fork the material git and override the spinner component in a custom component to do what you want to do with svgs and stuff: https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/material/progress-spinner I do not know enough to help you do it though

Comment: Yes, that is the only solution for it but i want to know how to perform that.